# Read/Write capability in BCS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs

Can someone tell me what exactly does "Read/Write Capability" means in Business Connectivity Services for SharePoint 2010?
I read it somewhere that this is a new feature in 2010 which was not present in 2007. But as far as I know, BCS was present in 2007 so I wonder how can BCS work without Read capability at least in 2007 because it doesn't look like a new feature to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007 there is a service named as **Business Data Catalog** which could be used to only read external systems.

However in SharePoint 2010 its re-designed as well as re-named as **Business Connectivity Service** or just BCS which comes with full read/write capability while interacting with external contents.

Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee906651%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for if you want to find out more about there differences.

If you are still confused then provide reference to where you have read that BDC provides read and write capabilities.

Comment: It is mentioned in one of the slide available on Microsoft website. Screenshot http://i.imgur.com/GrSdWYq.jpg

Comment: @FrankMartin I am pretty sure this slide is for SharePoint 2010 not 2007 as its referencing BCS not BDC.

Comment: Yeah I mixed up the BCS part with 2007.